# Dynamically add Edittext to a relative layout under an existing editText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to add an `editText` dynamically to a relative layout. the layout contains an `editText` already. I need to add the new `editText` below the existing one.

```
EditText designation1 = new EditText(context);
designation1.setHint("designation");
designation1.setSingleLine(true);
```

and my layout is

```
layoutExp = 
    (RelativeLayout) childView.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_edit_exp);
```

and my existing edit Text is

```
designation = (EditText)childView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDesignatn);
```

Comment: and you tried what, already ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and specifiy the relative position with the `addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ...)` (this is the programmatic equivalent for `android:below` XML attribute):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.editTextDesignatn);
layoutExp.addView(designation1, params);
```

Comment: i using a button click for adding text boxes dynamically. but the button click responds only for ist time. the 2nd time it never create the editText

Comment: it's probably created at the same position, that's why you don't see it

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible if You set for example a LinearLayout under Your existing EditText. Give an ID to this LinearLayout and then You could put Your dynamic EditText to this LinearLayout like

```
    YourLinearLayout.addView(YourDynamicEditText);
```